# what are other options for avoiding to expose google api key

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, api-key

When creating chrome extensions that play with the youtube data api, the api key is used. But is there any other way to get data from google servers instead of exposing our personal api key in the xmlhttprequest, apart from the naive way of asking the user to create his/her own api in their account and input that to use it in the extension?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) if you don't want to use API keys you can use OAuth 2.0 credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to Google for best practices.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application), obtain an access token through [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) API, and then use that token in the XMLHttpRequests.